# c#: Not finding object in list

Tags: c#, list

I am using LINQ `.Find()` and it's not stopping when it finds a match. I have:

```
List<ipFound> ipList = new List<ipFound>();

ipFound ipTemp = ipList.Find(x => x.ipAddress == srcIP); 

if (ipTemp == null) {
   // this is always null
}

public class ipFound
{
    public System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress;
    public int bytesSent;
    public int bytesReceived;
    public int bytesTotal;
}
```

Any ideas? I'm going nuts over here.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the item is actually in the list?

Comment: `Find` is not part of LINQ. It's a method specifically on `List` that pre-dates LINQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `.Equals` instead of `==`.

```
var a = IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4");
var b = IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4");
Console.WriteLine(a == b);  // False
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));  // True
```

In the sample above, `a == b` is `False` because those are two different objects. However, `a.Equals(b)` is `True` because they have equal values.

Comment: This; there is a subtle but key difference between referential and semantic equality. Are two variables equal because they point to the same location in memory, or are two variables equal because they point to two places in memory that have identical state? Which definition is "better" depends on the objects being compared and the specific context in which they are being compared. Both may be "right" for the same object in different scenarios.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`IPAddress.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytw09x9b.aspx) instead of comparing references (`==`):

```
ipFound ipTemp = ipList.Find(x => x.ipAddress.Equals(srcIP));
```

As a side note, usually class names are `PascalCased` (`IPFound` vs. `ipFound`)

**Example:** http://ideone.com/lAeiMm